# Ionic Pro: Live Deploy on Windows

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, windows-10-universal

I'm building an ionic-pro app. I'm working on Windows 10. I have live deploy working on iOS working on my Mac, following the instruction on the video's. But when I do the same for a different app on Windows 10 machine. Building a Windows Universal App, live deploy of pro is not triggered when I commit to the ionic repo and do a deploy on the Master channel. This should work in Windows or not? I can't find any documentation on that but only that it should work on all platforms. Anyone?

- ionic 3.19.0
- cordova 7.1.0
- npm 3.10.10

  `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^2.0.3">
      <variable name="APP_ID" value="{hereIsMyAppId}" />
      <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Master" />
      <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="auto" />
      <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
      <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
  </plugin>`

What could possibly go wrong there?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I cant seem to find anything on if Deploy works with Windows....

Comment: I asked a question on there support form. They admitted 'Live deploy' is not working still on the Windows platform which is a big disappointment and a missed opportunity in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

At nov 29, 2017 the Ionic support team responded with this answer:

> Hi Olivier,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to the Ionic Pro support team.
>
> Sorry you're having trouble. Unfortunately the Windows platform is not  supported by Deploy. I apologize that our docs don't make that clear. If  you have any other questions or there's anything else I can help you with let me know.
>
> Cheers,
> Brian Manning | Customer Advocate | Ionic

Comment: You know why it's not supported?